# What does SAGA's flow connectivity show?

Tags: qgis, saga, watershed, strahler

In the 'Channel network and drainage basins' algorithm from SAGA in QGIS, a couple of maps are generated. I can't seem to find any documentation on the different output maps. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The 'flow connectivity' output shows how fragmented are your channels.

In the picture below the channels colored in blue/purple are the less fragmented (runoffs and sediments can flow 'freely') compared to the others colored parts where no channels can actually be found or where channels exist but are fragmented by natural obstructions or engineered structures such as dams and weirs.

[image]

You could use a OSM or Google Satellite basemap to help you to understand and visualize the potential discontinuities within your flow connectivity layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea what the values actually mean and how they are generated?